# Open local file with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, hyperlink, asp.net-4.0

I'm using ASP.Net 4, this code for open local file (this site is IISlocal and 25.docx file in local)

address file:

```
\\shear_file\Site\Files\25.docx
```

link:

```
 <a href="file://///shear_file/Site/Files/25.docx" >25</a>
```

If i run the site with IIS and click on link, it doesn't open. But save this page and open page Stored and click on link. its open open file!!

and use this code:

```
Response.Redirect(@"file://///shear_file/Site/Files/25.docx");
```

Not open file!

Comment: Do you receive any errors? A cause for this could be because the account under which the IIS proces runs does not have access to that share.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: Not shown error and Link does not work.